# Dynamic DropdownButton and FutureBuilder - refreshing on item change

Tags: flutter

I am building a simple screen with a drop-down list fetching values from Firebase in _fetchEquipmentCategories function. I then use FutureBuilder to render the drop-down items based on the results of firestore database call. The problem I observe is whenever I select an item in drop-down, it re-renders and as part of that, the selected value is reset. What am I missing?

```
  List<String> list = <String>['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];
  late Future<List<EquipmentCategory>> categories;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('initState');
    categories = _fetchEquipmentCategories();
    // print("Length after init: ${categories.length}");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // print("Length before build: ${categories.length}");
    String dropdownValue = list.first;
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          return false;
        },
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: categories,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                // while data is loading:
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      valueColor:
                          new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue)),
                );
              } else {
                print("Refreshing");
                return Container(
                    color: CupertinoColors.white,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Column(children: <Widget>[
                            DropdownButton<String>(
                              // value: null,
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                              elevation: 16,
                              style:
                                  const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                              underline: Container(
                                height: 2,
                                color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                              ),
                              onChanged: (String? value) {
                                // This is called when the user selects an item.
                                setState(() {
                                  dropdownValue = value!;
                                  print("Dropdown value: $dropdownValue");
                                });
                              },
                              items: snapshot.data
                                  .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                                      (EquipmentCategory value) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                  value: value.id,
                                  child: Text(value.name),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                            )
                          ])
                        ]));
              }
            }));
  }

  Future<List<EquipmentCategory>> _fetchEquipmentCategories() async {
    List<EquipmentCategory> result = [];
    print("_fetchEquipmentCategories");
    //Fetch categories from firebase
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    await db.collection("equipmentCategories").get().then(
      (querySnapshot) {
        for (var docSnapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {
          print(
              "Adding category ${docSnapshot.id} => ${docSnapshot.data()['name']}");
          result.add(
              EquipmentCategory(docSnapshot.id, docSnapshot.data()['name']));
        }
      },
      onError: (e) => print("Error completing: $e"),
    );
    return result;
  }

  _printCategoriesValues() {
    print('_printCategoriesValues');
    categories.then((result) => {
          print(result.length),
          for (var cat in result) {print('Category: ${cat.name}')}
        });
  }

  _browseEquipment() {
    print('_browseEquipment');
  }
}

class EquipmentCategory {
  String id;
  String name;

  EquipmentCategory(this.id, this.name);
}
```

Comment: `String dropdownValue = list.first;` needs to be in state, not in build.